# Need to show that this converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$ and $a_{n+2}=\frac{na_{n+1}+a_n}{n+1}$
I need to prove that this converges. Here is my try :

Let's look at $\lim_{n->∞}a_{n+2}$ For an instance suppose it does converge and let $\lim_{n->∞}a_{n+2}=L$

So $L=\frac{nL+L}{n+1}$ and i know that $n->∞$ So right hand side of the equation will be L so $L=L$ is satisfied, therefore it does converge.

Would you say this way of thinking is correct? Or Should I try a formal one.

Btw, it's given in question that $L=1-e^{-1}$, And I'm also asked to prove that L equals this.

I tried taking the $ln$ of each side, but couldn't end anywhere.

Comment: You could try to prove that $(a_{2n})$  and  $(a_{2n+1})$ adjacent.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I've wrote the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ wrong. Please re-check :(

Comment: `suppose it does converge [...] therefore it does converge` That's circular and proves nothing.

Comment: You will need to create a more formal proof. You assumed that the limit exists so you cannot use this to prove that the sequence converges; all you have done is not found any contradiction after assuming the limit exists.

Comment: Hint: $$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=-\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n+1}$$

Comment: As Hugh noted, if you suppose $A$ is true, then your conclusion needs to be that $A$ is true.

Comment: There is an error: $L=2-e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

we have

$a_1=1$

$a_2=2$

$a_3=\frac{a_2+a_1}{1+1}=\frac{3}{2}$

$a_4=\frac{2a_3+a_2}{2+1}=\frac{5}{3}$

$a_{n+2}$ is the barycenter of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ with respective weights $n$ and $1$.

So all $a_n$ are in $[1,2]$.

You should prove by induction that

$(a_{2n+1})$ is increasing  while $(a_{2n})$ is decreasing.

both are bounded.

So they converge and it's not difficult to show that theire limits are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the argument is flawed under many respects.

Let's try a different sequence, by way of example. Set
$$
a_1=1,\qquad a_{n+1}=2a_n+1
$$
Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$; then $L=2L+1$, so $L=-1/2$. Did we prove the sequence converges? Of course not! It would be absurd that a positive sequence converges to a negative limit.

Another example. Consider $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+1}{4a_n+1}$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then
$$
L=\frac{L+1}{4L+1}
$$
so $4L^2+L=L+1$ that gives $L=\pm\frac{1}{2}$. However, the sequence is positive. What we have proved is that

> if the sequence converges, then the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

But we have *not* proved convergence. This can be done in various ways, but it is not the main point.

Your argument is faulty also when you substitute $a_n$ with $L$. Both $n$ and $a_n$ depend on $n$ and you cannot substitute one limit and not the other. It would be the same as saying that, since $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{x}=0
$$
which you surely know is utterly wrong. Anyway, if you find that $L=L$ you don't even have a clue on what the limit *can* be. No information about convergence at all.

Comment: Great thanks. How do you think I should approach here? I see that the sequence is bounded from below, Should I look for whether its monotonic or not? Couldn't think of any way

Comment: @Xenidia Those are the standard attempts to try; maybe computing some terms can give you a clue about the thing. Also, since you're given that the limit is $1-e^{-1}$, you can try proving (by induction), that $1$ is an upper bound.